# Al llamar una función de Python en Electron sale error: require is not defined at OnClick

Tags: python, login, electron, onclick

Estoy intentando fusionar *Electron* con *Python*, pero tengo un error el cual es el siguiente. Cuando el usuario hace clic en un botón quiero que accione una función hecha en *Python*, pero en lugar de eso tengo el siguiente error **"*require is not defined at OnClick*"**

El código *Python* es el siguiente:

```
import sys

def login():
    # Obtengo los datos que envia electron
    data = sys.argv[1]
    print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    login()
```

El código en *Electron* es este:

```
function OnClick(){
     >const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell')<
     >const path = require('path');<

     const login = 'Hola Mundo';

     const opcoes = {
          scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, '../_engine/auth'),
          args : [login]
     }
     const logIn = new PythonShell('auth.py', opcoes);

     logIn.on('message', function(message) {
         console.log(message)
     })
}
```

El error esta en el JavaScript en las lineas que marque entre los signos ">" y "<"

Comment: Puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/327867/edit) copiando el error que aparece, si es que aparece algun error, o indicando cuál es el obstáculo al intentar hacer eso.

Comment: Quizás debas poner los `require` afuera de la función `OnClick`, más arriba en el código.

Comment: Probe poner los require fuera de la funcion pero es el mimso problema

Comment: Sugiero que edites la pregunta agregando cuál es el error exacto que aparece y si es posible saber en qué línea o la pila de errores completa. Se puede usar el signo `> ` para darle formato amarillo al error.

Comment: Encontré este reporte de problema en el _GitHub_ de _Electron_ que al parecer está solucionado. Quizás te sirva. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241

Comment: Gracias este reporte resolvio el problema, la solucion es colocar la linea "webPreferences:{nodeIntegration: true}" en mi BrowserWindow

Comment: De ser así considera publicar la respuesta

Comment: @ezequiel La edición no está tan mal, de todos modos, yo decía que al copiar y pegar la pila de error en la pregunta, se puede poner al principio de cada línea un signo `> ` para que salga el error con un fondo amarillo. Por otra parte, como ya dijo Aprendiz, ya hice una respuesta a la pregunta. Es posible marcarla como correcta o esperar a que alguien responda con otra alternativa y ver si alguna es la correcta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el siguiente reporte de problema en el *GitHub* de *Electron*:

- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241

En este reporte, según [la respuesta de bokele](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241#issuecomment-498064435), hay que agregar en el archivo **index.js** lo siguiente:

```
const w = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
})
```

Es decir, hay que agregar en el `BrowserWindow` lo siguiente:

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
}
```

Nota: No necesariamente hay que agregar un `new BrowserWindow`, solamente se debería usar `new` si aún el `BrowserWindow` no existe.